# haml code how to make it has some indention

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code that displaying element like below

```
    Mytable
1.  line1
2.  line2
3.  line3
4.  line4
```

but I want it have indention, like belows

```
     Mytable
   1.  line1
   2.  line2
   3.  line3
   4.  line4
```

My code is at here

```
      %div{:class => 'test1'}
        %table#tablename
          %thead
            %tr
              %th.lead Mytable

          %tbody              
            %tr
              %center
              %td 1.line1
            %tr
              %td 2. line2
            %tr 
              %td 3. line3
            %tr
              %td 4. line4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it. Here's one.[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Z9b/)

```
<div class="test1">
    <table id="tablename">
       <thead>
       <tr><th class="lead">Mytable</th></tr>    
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1. line1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2. line2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3. line3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>4. line4</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.test1
{
    padding-left:20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a padding to the first cell in each row using CSS:

```
table#tablename tbody tr td:first-child {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

See an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ramuw